# iOS Storyboard in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have started an iOS app with storyboard. In my app, mainStoryBoard starts with navigation controller. From navigation's view controller, I pass the controller to a second viewcontroller with a push segue by programatically `([self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"currencyClick" sender:self])`. On the second view controller I have a button. On button click I want to go back to navigation's viewcontroller like `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` but here `self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES` is not working . In my project I unticked `Shows navigation Bar` in Navigationcontroller.

**NavigationController-(root viewcontroller)-> viewController --(push segue with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"currencyClick" sender:self];)-->CurrencyViewcontroller**

In currencyviewController I have a button. On button click I want to implement navigation back button click event. How do I implement a BACK Button programmatically, `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` is not working in this case.

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to call secondcontroller in your first view controller use:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mainStoryBoard" bundle: nil];

SecondViewController *rvc = (SecondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerNameInYourStoryBoard"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES ];
```

instead of self performSegue... Then in your second controller pop should work.

Comment: Thanks Luciano Rodríguez.